# PouchDB and CouchDB Replication hangs browser

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I have an application that syncs between CouchDB and PouchDB. The CouchDB has about 100 documents that are replicated to the browser using PouchDB when the application loads for the first time.

A few files are about 1 MB and have about 600-700 revisions. The problem is that the replication takes a lot of time and hangs most of the time. I tried to debug it and I found that replication of these 100 documents is taking a lot of time.

My application runs from the local PouchDB database that is synchronized from CouchDB at startup (when user logs in for 1st time). I have no clue now what to do and how to improve its performance. How should I change the architecture of my application. Please help

Comment: Do you have any errors or any hints why it hangs? Replication wich PouchDB is async so that should not "hang" the browser.

Comment: I tried to debug this issue. Possibly I have some good amount of data in the document, and the HTTP request sends the complete information included the revisions info while replicating. And that is why the replication takes some time. Not sure why the browser hangs. It sometimes gives the Aww, Snap error.